# How To Call iPod Library In A User Application

Tags: iphone

I would like to know is it possible to access iPod (GUI) in a user application, so that user can select few song and create his playlist. For better user interaction i would like to use
default iPod GUI. Is there any way to call it in our application. It is not easy to create a similar GUI like iPod library.
Please try to help me in solving this problem.

Thank You
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference.pdf

The MPMediaPickerController will provide you with an interface for picking media from the iPod library.

Answer (score 0):

There is Ipod access starting with SDK 3.0 in  OS 3.0, heres a link to the documentation, i never used it to i cant give you details of what you can or cannot do. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide.pdf

That document should have everything you need to get started.